# Python 3.6 vs 3.5 TypeError message on string concatenation

Tags: python, string, typeerror, python-3.5, python-3.6

`'Hello ' + 1` doesn't return the same error message on Python 3.5 and 3.6:

- Python 3.5.2: `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`
- Python 3.6.0: `TypeError: must be str, not int`

Is it a simple change in wording or is there something more subtle behind?

Comment: Why do you ask?  Do you have an `except TypeError` handler that's dependent on the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: No, I just wondered if it has something to do with the `typing` module or typing for variables introduced in 3.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was just some cleaning up of code that involved string objects. It also introduced some changes in the error messages when incompatible objects are used to make them a bit "more informative".

See: *[Issue 26057 - Avoid nonneeded use of `PyUnicode_FromObject()`](https://bugs.python.org/issue26057)* that introduced this change if you're interested.

There's nothing subtle here, it is still illegal and all, the author changed the error message to what he considered a bit clearer.

*Edit:* I created *[Issue 29116 - Make `str` and `bytes` error messages on concatenation conform with other sequences](http://bugs.python.org/issue29116)* to address this specific message while also addressing the error message for bytes types that have had a similarly verbose response when we do silly things with them:

```
>>> b'' + ''
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: In fact the new error message is worse, any object that implements `__radd__` correctly can work here so `"must be str"` is plainly wrong.  The error message you get with switched operands is clearer imo: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.

Comment: Thanks Jim, but as @wim said the new message isn't clearer. Too bad such a choice was made...

Comment: @wim Yeah, this needs to be raised in the tracker.

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux it is simple to get changed, I'll update the answer if it does.